# First, second, and third person mixed in a sentence

Tags: grammatical-person

"Ms. Bar sneaks in to eat our candy."
"You want me to talk to them."

My mother is a fifth-grade teacher, and she's currently covering the first, second, and third person points of view. She is generally what I would call a "reliable source," but she wants my opinion on which person each of these is written in. I can't make up my mind, and the Google isn't helping much.

Is the person determined by the subject of the sentence? Does it depend on all of the nouns and pronouns and follow an order of preference (*exemplī grātiā*, if "my" is present, it's first person; if "me" and "your" are both present, "your" takes precedence, and the sentence is second person)? Is the person of a sentence even this technical, or must it be interpreted more generally from the surrounding passage?

(I'm not sure if I'm making sense or asking too many questions. Feel free to guide me in making my query clearer and more concise!)

Comment: I don't think "the person of the sentence" is a coherent or useful concept. Person is a property of pronouns and (in most European languages) of a verb, specifically as regards its subject. In many languages (eg Hebrew and Georgian) the verb shows the person of the object as well as the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ms. Bar sneaks in to eat our candy."-

"Ms. Bar" is the subject and the pronoun she can replace Ms. Bar. Also since she "sneaks" and has not "been sneaking", or "is sneaking", this implies information that only an outside, all observant party would know. So by itself, this would be in the third person.

"You want me to talk to them."

(Is this a question or a statement?) I guess it doesn't really matter because either way, the speaker is addressing "you", and this pronoun suggests that the sentence is written in the second person.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_pronoun)

Comment: Thanks! So, to make sure, it's the subject of the sentence that determines the person of the sentence?

Comment: For something to be "second-person narrative," "you" has to consistently be used as the subject.  This can be done in role-playing games (think Dungeons and Dragons) or "how-to" narratives, including some driving directions.  Songs can be written that way as well.  It can be used in a short story or other fictional work, but it's very rare.

Comment: @Steven Your comment would make the definitive answer: '**nth person narrative**' means 'using the nth person consistently as the subject'. Two usages of 'nth person' are being confused here.